# Awk - delete oldest duplicate lines, preserving the latest duplicate + deleting one line above deleted duplicate

Tags: awk, duplicates

I have input in a following format:

```
#1655636921
cd
#1655636926
history
#1655637510
history
#1655637934
ls
#1655637934
ls
#1655638524
cd
#1655638927
ls
#1655638928
history
```

and I would like to search for duplicates (in lines, that do not start with '**#**' OR detect duplicates only in even lines), delete all previous duplicates (keeping only the latest one) + for each deleted duplicate delete one previous line, so the output would look like this:

```
#1655638524
cd
#1655638927
ls
#1655638928
history
```

I am new to awk and I couldn't find any solution even with preserving latest duplicates, the only related solution that I have found is:

```
awk '!visited[$0]++'
```

Which deletes only latest duplicates preserving the oldest one.
Thank you very much in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried to solve your problem. See [ask].

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have seen a lot of text editing topics answered without tried approach, but I added what I have tried (found) so far, I apologize for my lack of information regarding the tried approach, but I am new to awk and even after hours of searching I didn't even found how to even preserve the newest duplicates, not mentioning deleting previous line of old duplicates.

Comment: Sometimes you will get an answer without showing any attempt (if someone's feeling particularly bored or finds the problem particularly interesting or they just don't know what they're doing), but usually your question will just get downvoted and closed. Yours already had 2 close votes before I commented and 3 close votes is all it takes to close a question which meant 1 more close vote and it'd have been closed too. Thank you for adding your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ tac file | awk '!/^#/{f = !seen[$0]++} f' | tac
#1655638524
cd
#1655638927
ls
#1655638928
history
```

If you don't have the `tac` command on your system you can create a `tac` function to do the same thing the command does, i.e. reverse the order of input lines, using just the mandatory POSIX tools `awk`, `sort`, and `cut`:

```
tac() { awk -v OFS='\t' '{print NR, $0}' "${@:--}" | sort -k1,1rn | cut -f2-; }
```

or if your `cat` has a `-n` argument (non-POSIX) or you have `nl` (POSIX but not mandatory):

```
tac() { nl "${@:--}" | sort -k1,1rn | cut -f2-; }
tac() { cat -n "${@:--}" | sort -k1,1rn | cut -f2-; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- OP mentions processing by `'line'` so this means `ls` and `ls *.txt` are to be treated as two distinct commands (ie, both will show up in the final output)
- OP mentions detecting duplicates only in `'even lines'` which implies we do not need to worry about nested linefeeds (in either the `#comment` or the command), nor multi-line `#comment`s

One `awk` idea that eliminates the need for any other programs:

```
awk '
/^#/ { comment=$0; next }
     { comments[$0]=comment                   # associate previous line/comment with current command

       delete lineno2cmd[cmd2lineno[$0]]      # delete previous line number associated with this command
       lineno2cmd[FNR]=$0                     # associate the current line number with this command; this array used to generate output in line number order (ie, maintain ordering of lines)
       cmd2lineno[$0]=FNR                     # maintain reverse link from command to line number; this array used solely to make sure only one entry in lineno2cmd[] is associated with the current command
     }
END  { for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++)                   # loop through list of line numbers and ...
           if (i in lineno2cmd) {             # if line number is an index in the lineno2cmd[] array then ...
              printf "%s\n%s\n", comments[lineno2cmd[i]], lineno2cmd[i]
           }
     }
' history.dat
```

If OP has access to `GNU awk (v 4.0+)` (for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` support) we can streamline this a bit:

```
awk '
/^#/ { comment=$0; next }
     { comments[$0]=comment
       cmd2lineno[$0]=FNR
     }
END  { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"     # sort array by the numerical values (ascending)
       for (i in cmd2lineno) {
           printf "%s\n%s\n", comments[i], i
           }
     }
' history.dat
```

These both generate:

```
#1655638524
cd
#1655638927
ls
#1655638928
history
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow there was a strange duplicate lingering and had to trim it out brute force :

```
    {m,g}awk'
    BEGIN {
     1      RS = "(\r?\n)?[#]"
     1      FS = (_="[ \t]*")"\n+"(_)
     1     OFS =  _=""
     1     ___ = "\21#"
    }    {
           ____[+__[$NF]]++
                 __[$NF] = NR ___ $+_
    } END {
     1         FS = "[0-9]+\21"
     1        OFS = ORS
     1          _ = ""
     1        $+_ = _
     1     delete  ____[_]
     1     delete ____[+_]

     4     for(_ in __) { if(!(+(___=__[_]) in ____)) {
     4         $+___=___
               sub("^[^\021]+\21[#]?","#",$+___)
     4     } }
           sub("^.+\n\n", ""); print }'
```

=

```
#1655638524
cd
#1655638927
ls
#1655638928
history
```